# How to convert RGB to a 1px base64 encoded data uri in php

Tags: php, image, base64

I'm trying to figure out a more efficient way to create a 1px by 1px image (jpg, png and gif) from a single RGB color code, in php.

The example below illustrates one method of doing it but I was hoping for some kind of algorithm that will get me the same output without having to load any libraries or php extensions.

**Example:**

```
function rgbToDataUri($r,$g,$b,$type)
{
    $im = imageCreateTrueColor(1, 1);

    imageFill($im, 0, 0, ImageColorAllocate($im,$r,$g,$b));

    ob_start();

    switch($type)
    {
        case 'gif':
            imageGif($im);
            break;
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            imageJpeg($im);
            break;
        default:
            imagePng($im);
    }

    $img = ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean();

    return 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($img);
}

echo rgbToDataUri(0,0,0,'gif');
```

Output:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAIAAAAQCBAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=
```

My goals are (in priority order):

1. Low memory consumption
2. High processor efficiency
3. High speed of processing

Requirements include supporting gif, jpg and png. Anywhere from 20 - 50 of these single pixel images will be created with each request (each pixel is independent of the others).

How does one produce the binary for a 1px single color image?

Comment: Your code is pretty simple/straightforward as it is. You almost certainly don't want to implement all of the various image formats by hand.

Comment: What about outputting a BMP? For a single pixel it's just about as efficient as the other three formats and is probably simple enough so you can produce the binary directly using a bit of bit shifting and `pack`ing without much work.

Comment: @amber Unfortunately, simplicity isn't the goal for this particular exercise.

Comment: @deceze I could produce a BMP in addition to the listed formatS but I do need to support those other formats as it's one of the primary requirements. Your method does sound interesting. How does one produce the binary directly for a 1px image? Maybe that should be my question.

Comment: Can you give us more context on what this is being used for?

Comment: @amber Unfortunately because of an ND I have to be scant with details but it is part of an API that generates color schemes.

Comment: You can produce BMPs by simply producing a few bytes of header, which can probably be static, and then cobble together the bits for a single pixel of color value. See the format description at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format for a start. A new question for that may indeed be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in this field. But I came across "[ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)" which is a native PHP extension to create and modify images. It can read, convert and write images in a variety of formats (over 100) including DPX, EXR, GIF, JPEG, JPEG-2000, PDF, PhotoCD, PNG, Postscript, SVG, and TIFF.

Comment: Does definitely not help him with his goals: low memory, cpu usage, speed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest keeping a binary string for every supported image of size 1x1 pixel and find a place where it stores the colour data (using available specs). Then you just put the needed colour there and do base64 encode.

This should do at least for PNG and GIF. They have palettes and all colour data is stored in one place. JPG, on the other hand, does not sotre plain RGB, so it is somewhat trickier (and definitely not the best choice for a 1x1 image).

Comment: I've considered this method but I'm afraid retrieval (latency) might be too much of a bottleneck for this particular exercise.

Comment: @BillH Modifying 4 bytes in a string which is already stored in memory is hardly a bottleneck. Doing base64 encoding might be one, but you could also implement encoded cache for values that you previously had or (if you have some knowledge on data) expect to have. However, the latter hits memory consumption, which is prio 1 over CPU usage.